# Custom pam auth module is causing login prompt to not enforce password

Tags: linux, security, pam

We have a custom pam module to authenticate our own users outside of linux. We have the module registered with the sshd and login pam files. Sshd works fine, but for some reason when doing a local console login if I try one of our users that exists, but give it a bad password it still lets the login proceed. I can see from logging that I am failing the authentication due to the bad password correctly, just the same as when I do it via ssh, but the login case seems to ignore it. I'm curious if I have the config setup wrong. Here is what the /etc/pamd/login looks like (our pam module is custom_pam.so):

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth       sufficient  custom_pam.so
auth [user_unknown=ignore success=ok ignore=ignore default=bad] pam_securetty.so
auth       substack     system-auth
auth       include      postlogin
account    sufficient     custom_pam.so
account    required     pam_nologin.so
account    include      system-auth
password   include      system-auth
# pam_selinux.so close should be the first session rule
session    required     pam_selinux.so close
session    required     pam_loginuid.so
session    optional     pam_console.so
# pam_selinux.so open should only be followed by sessions to be executed in the user context
session    required     pam_selinux.so open
session    required     pam_namespace.so
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session    include      system-auth
session    include      postlogin
-session   optional     pam_ck_connector.so
```

Is there anything obviously wrong with this? Or is there some way to turn on verbose logging for pam actions to perhaps see where it is getting a successful login from? I did test root and it fails expectedly with a wrong password.

Comment: What do you expect to happen?  Do you want to not allow standard system authentication to happen?  If so, you need to not include `system-auth`.

Comment: I want to authenticate any users that our system knows about (users not in the os) with our module, and if that fails to authenticate them fall back to the default linux auth methods. So even though root is not a user in our user db, I still want that to be able to login via the standard methods.

Comment: @womble, just to add I was doing some playing around and found that if i simply removed a "nullok" from the system-auth pam config everything works as expected, although I have no idea why. The generated system-auth had this line in it:
"auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so try_first_pass nullok"
If I remove the nullok from the end it all works.

Comment: If removing `nullok` from `pam_unix.so` makes everything work, I'm pretty sure that means there's a bug in your module, resetting the collected credential.  It's been a while since I've written a custom PAM module, though.

Comment: Yeah after looking up what nullok meant I was suspicious. I then actually commented out our custom pam modules altogether and was still hitting the issue. This made me think it was actually our nss module. I incorrectly assumed that the password property in the return structure for the getpwam and getpwuid calls was not used, so I was passing back an empty string for user lookups that matched our own users. I believe this was being interpreted as a null password and thus causing the nullok check to pass. Passing back "x" for our user lookups in nss fixed it.

Comment: Ain't PAM/NSS *fun*?